# Dynamically edit the href attribute

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I don't care what language it is, but I'd like this to be done automatically.
I have several links on my website that link to the same place regardless.
For example, on index.php, I have a home button that links href="index.php"
However, when I'm now in downloads/download.php, I need to manually adjust the location to href="../index.php"

Is there a way to do this dynamically? It really messes up considering I'm using the include function for the whole top navigation bar, and I can't really make it dynamic.
My ideal languages to accomplish this would be:
PHP > JavaScript = jQuery > AJAX

http://www.dioxidetech.com/

### Whatever is more efficient! Thank you!

Comment: Yes, you definitely should use PHP for this. Without client-side scripting (like in the most crawlers), the links would just appear broken elsewise.

Comment: Btw, "AJAX" is not a language but a buzzword… :-)

Comment: Perhaps you need to set the full url in the links,  you can use the $_SERVER global to achieve this. [http://www.php.net/manual/es/reserved.variables.server.php](http://www.php.net/manual/es/reserved.variables.server.php)

Comment: @Bergi I have very little experience with PHP, how would you do it?

Comment: I might not understand your question, but what about the <BASE> tag?

Comment: Seems to be working, I didn't exactly understand that tag before, but now I think I got the hang of it so far, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use relative URLS:
Instead of linking to ../index.php, link to: /
Other links can be relative too, like: /downloads/download.php

Btw. If using a downloads subdir, why not have an index.php there too?
You dont need to link to index-files, just link to theire containing folder.

Comment: Does this require the Base tag? or I can do it, without the tag? Also, thanks for the second part! I didn't know that! @Olavxxx

Comment: You just link like so: 
<a href="/" title="E.T. Phone Home">Home</a> , <a href="/downloads/" title="Ramsi - Hacking with kazaa">Downloads</a>

You can use / to start off at the root.
Or you can use: blah/foo.php

This will find the blah folder within current folder.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(computing)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a local directory use a URL. So, you can place `http://example.com/index.php` as your `href` attribute for all of those.

You can also use the super global `$_SERVER` to retrieve the base URL.

```
function getHomeURL() {
    return $_SERVER[ "HTTP_ORIGIN" ];
}
```

This way you can call the function when you need to place href attributes.

```
<a href="<?php echo getHomeURL(); ?>">Home</a>
```

I hope this helped.

---

[More on PHP Super globals](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php)

[More on PHP $_SERVER super global](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php)

Answer (score 0):

Another way to approach this but maybe not the most straight-forward method to keep all of your stuff neatly in one place is via a switch()

you make a single index.php file that looks something like this:

```
<?php
include 'navbar.php';
$pagelink = $_GET['link'];
switch($pagelink)
{
    case 'home';
        $link = "home.php";
        break;
    case 'download';
        $link = "download/downloads.php";
        break;
    case 'about';
        $link = "about/about.php";
        break;
    case 'contact';
        $link = "contact/contact_us.php";
        break;
    case 'this';
        $link = "something/else/in/a/different/folder/this.php";
        break;
}
include $link;
include 'footer.php';
?>
```

Then all you have to do is formulate all of your links something like this:

```
<a href="index.php?link=download" title="Downloads" target="_self">Downloads</a>
```

and you'l never leave your index page, loading (including) each and every page, wherever it may be located, within the index page.

Comment: What might be an issue with this one, is if he wants to use header commands (like file attachment at download page).

Of course he can do some selective actions in the header file too :-)